# Element hidden by CSS still takes up space on page- how do I set display: none conditionally?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a web application that has been written in VB.net. On the login page for the app, there is an error message that's displayed conditionally, if the user clicks the Log In button having not entered anything into the password box:

The functionality of this all currently works correctly, and the message is only displayed when nothing has been entered into the password field, and there is a click off the form, or on the 'Proceed' button.

However, there is space left where the message would be displayed, even when it isn't:

I have been asked to remove this space, so that the 'Forgotten Password' link is displayed directly below the Password text box when the error message is not displayed.

However, despite setting the visibility attribute of the error message element in the CSS, I can't actually seem to remove the space when the message is not shown.

The only way I have found of doing this is to set the element's `display` attribute to `none` in the CSS- but this obviously then means that the message is not displayed when the password field is left blank.

The CSS set on the field is:

```
.loginarea .loginerror {
    color: Red;
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

and the form field is displayed with:

```
<body class="login">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        ...
        <div id="divLoginBg" runat="server" class="loginbg">
            <div class="loginarea">
                <asp:Panel ID="Step1" CssClass="greyblock" runat="server">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" ValidationGroup="loginpage" autocomplete="off" TextMode="Password" runat="server" /><br />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Req2" ValidationGroup="loginpage" ControlToValidate="Password" runat="server" CssClass="loginerror" ErrorMessage="Please enter your password" /><br />
                    ...
                </asp:Panel>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

How can I set the element's `display` attribute to `none` conditionally? i.e. its `display` should only be `none` when there is no password entered in the text box?

Comment: HTML & CSS added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden` as using the first make the tag in question not to appear on the page at all and there will be no space allocated for it.
Using the second makes the tag not visible, but space is allocated for it on the page

Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Meziano/4zk9scex/)

Comment: As I mentioned in my OP, I tried setting `display:none`, but this obviously means that the element is never displayed- I do want it to be displayed when there is nothing entered in the Password box, and the user tries to log in, or clicks somewhere outside the form on the web page. The problem with using `visibility: hidden` is that the space where the message would appear is still displayed even when the message itself is not.

Comment: Use 2 css-classes: one to make the message 'disappear' and another to make it visible. Add the suitable css-class and remove the other accordingly to your logic

Comment: Ok- that makes sense, but I'm not sure how/ where I apply that logic? Can I add an `if` statement to the `CssClass` attribute of the `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator />` HTML tag?

Comment: Take a look at the provided Fiddle. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for providing the Fiddle- that is almost exactly what I want... The only change I would like to make, is rather than have the CSS class change based on the `click` event, I want it to change based on whether or not the text box is empty- is this possible?

Comment: Of course. In the Fiddle it is just an example how to do it. Use instead the change event like so:  $('.your-css-class-text-box').on('change', function(event){
   
    
  });

Comment: Brilliant- that's got it changing based on whether there's text in the box or not... However, I noticed when expecting the element in the browser, that the class shown is always the `loginerror` class, and never the `loginerrorhidden` class... `loginerrorhidden` has the attribute `display:none`, `loginerror` doesn't, so the space is never actually removed... When inspecting the element in the browser, the HTML shows the attribute `visibility: hidden` even though I'm not actually setting that in the code... Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189068/discussion-between-meziane-and-noble-surfer).

Answer (score 0):

use this css

```
.loginarea .loginerror {
display:none;
color: Red;
font-size: 1.8em;
```

}

and if you are using any jquery for filed validation which check for empty username or password. just write this to show this message
$('.loginerror').show();

Comment: I tried that, as mentioned in my OP- but this means that the message is never displayed. It sounds like jquery would possibly work- but it's been years since I've used that, so not really sure how I would implement it... Could you give an example?

Comment: If you have any id to that error msg html element you can use javascript also just add this line in your script after validation  document.getElementById("id").style.display = "block"; along with the css i have given above

Comment: and if you want to use jquery give this js link <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and after that where you want to show this msg just write $('.loginerror').show();